# My SQL upgrade to version 5.5 issue

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to upgrade from 5.1 to 5.5, but while dumping and restoring I'm getting some issues with the views in different schemas.

It's throwing an error :

> 'Couldn't execute 'SHOW FIELDS FROM `---view`': View 'schemaname.*****view' references invalid table(s) or column(s) or function(s) or definer/invoker of view lack rights to use them (1356)'

Comment: You should show us some lines from the dump-script that cause the error.

Comment: Its a normal dump query like , mysqldump -u <login> -p<pwd> -- routines <schema> > "path"

Comment: Was it error during dumping or restoring?

Answer (score 0):

Possible it was error during dumping invalid views. Check those views using `SHOW CREATE VIEW` command, or analyze them using metadata from `information_schema.views`. Check that definers (which are MySQL user accounts) are correct.